# Geary: mail - Broken Theme and icons

Tags: themes, pantheon-mail, icons, flatpak

After I have installed Geary mail client from the Flathub repository, the icons are bad rendered, with vertical separators bethween. Any solution ? The version is 3.38 I think.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it does look pretty bad.
This appears to be some quirk when using the elementary icon theme with Geary.
It's possible to set the `GTK_THEME` to the *Adwaita* icon theme which looks much better.
You can set the theme when running Geary with the following Flatpak command.

```
flatpak run --env=GTK_THEME=Adwaita org.gnome.Geary
```

To avoid the hassle of opening Geary from the command-line you can make this setting the default behavior by *overriding* it.

Use the following command to override this behavior for the Geary Flatpak installed in *per-user* mode.

```
flatpak override --user --env=GTK_THEME=Adwaita org.gnome.Geary
```

To override this setting for a *system-wide* installation of the Geary Flatpak, use this command.

```
sudo flatpak override --system --env=GTK_THEME=Adwaita org.gnome.Geary
```

Comment: Many thanks ! I will try these options.